# For loop question: Label each store for correlation value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I define my code to find correlation between 'day' and 'sales' each store by using this code

```
def store_corr(store_num):
  subset= df[df['store']== store_num]
  subset= subset[['day','dollar_sales']]
  subset_corr = subset.corr()
  corr_val = subset_corr.iloc[0,1]
  return corr_val
```

And Next step is running for loop each store like this

```
store = df.store.unique()    
   for i in store:
      corre = store_corr(i)
      print(corre)
```

But All I need are columns that provide store_num and corr for each store, so How I can coding to get output like this:

---

| store | corre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.26 |
| 2 | 0.12 |
| 3 | -0.96 |

Thank you

Comment: Please add some sample data, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15873043).

Comment: sample data provide in this link: https://prnt.sc/RB9tx8vXPMBm

Comment: _'sample data provide in this link'_ the link does not work

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this:

```py
store = df.store.unique() 
values = {"store": [], "corre": []}   
for i in store:
    corre = store_corr(i)
    values["store"].append(i)
    values["corre"].append(corre)
    print(i, corre)
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
```

df dataframe should have the output you want

Comment: If it is ok you can accept answer by clicking next to it so it get an accept answer status

Comment: Is that possible to pick up only the last values for this dict? because lastet list ondict has complete with all corre with store.

Comment: what do you mean by last values?

Comment: I mean like this sir
https://prnt.sc/oam0TwP3_Imm

last compute, it's have all store_num and corre

Comment: you have modified the print I made, change the print value by: ```print("store: ", i, "corre: ", corre)``` instead of ```print(values)``` the lastest will print the dictionary which is increasing every iteration. The initial print I made is only printing the latest

Comment: Ok sir, I got this. Thank you very much

Comment: I will appreciate if you accept my answer as valid.